# How to make int variable visible to other class from GUI JButton

Tags: java, class, variables, declaration

I'm trying to access the int `myInt` in this GUI form class from another class. The method does pass the input variable to `myInt` properly but I have not been able to make it visible to the other java file.  I have been reading about scope and class declarations and have been able to muddle along up until now, but I am doing something wrong here. Nothing I have tried has worked.

```
package com.jdividend.platform.allocation;

import com.ib.client.*;
import com.jdividend.platform.model.*;
import com.jdividend.platform.trader.*;
import com.jdividend.platform.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

/**
 * Dialog to show the account size allowed info.
 */
public class AllocationDialog extends JDialog {

    /* inner class to define the "about" model */
    public static class AllocationTableModel extends TableDataModel {

        private AllocationTableModel() {
            String[] aboutSchema = {"Property", "Value"};
            setSchema(aboutSchema);
        }

    }

    public AllocationDialog(JFrame parent) {
        super(parent);
        init();
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void init() {
        setModal(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Allocation - JDividend");

        JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            contentPanel.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            panel.setLayout(null);

            JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
            panel_1.setBounds(84, 146, 274, 19);
            panel.add(panel_1);

            JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Total account cash and margin that");
            panel_1.add(lblNewLabel);

            JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
            panel_2.setBounds(84, 163, 274, 19);
            panel.add(panel_2);

            JLabel lblJdividendIsAllowed = new JLabel("JDividend is allowed to trade with.");
            panel_2.add(lblJdividendIsAllowed);

            JFormattedTextField formattedTextField = new JFormattedTextField();
            formattedTextField.setBounds(172, 189, 100, 20);
            panel.add(formattedTextField);

            JButton btnOk = new JButton("OK");
            btnOk.setBounds(121, 221, 89, 23);
            panel.add(btnOk);
            btnOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    try {
                        int myInt = Integer.parseInt(formattedTextField.getText());
                        System.out.println(myInt);
                        //do some stuff
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                        System.out.println("Not a number");
                        //do you want
                    }

                    JButton btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
                    btnCancel.setBounds(238, 220, 89, 23);
                    panel.add(btnCancel);

                    formattedTextField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                            JButton button = new JButton("OK");
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
        }

        String serverVersion = "Disconnected from server";
        Trader trader = Dispatcher.getInstance().getTrader();
        if (trader != null) {
            int version = trader.getAssistant().getServerVersion();
            if (version != 0) {
                serverVersion = String.valueOf(version);
            }
        }

        TableDataModel aboutModel = new AllocationTableModel();

        getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 400));

        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        Enumeration<?> propNames = properties.propertyNames();

        while (propNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = (String) propNames.nextElement();
            String value = properties.getProperty(key);
            String[] row = {key, value};
            aboutModel.addRow(row);
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`myInt` should be declared inside the class, but outside of any method implementations:

```
public class AllocationDialog extends JDialog {

    public int myInt;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I tried this earlier but did not have effect on the myInt vairable in the subclass method.